# i recently used JCrop in my laravel project , but although i choose a photo and its loaded , i get validation error image is requred

Tags: laravel, jcrop, laravel-validation

I followed this `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aflTCbGdzDc` tutorial, and I managed to include `Jcrop` in my `laravel` project, everything is working fine. I click on `choose image`, I crop the image, and the image is shown in the `jcrop image box`. but when I submit the form. I get the error in my `validation` that says, `image is required` ( i wrote a `validation` for my image file). why am I getting this error ??? the image is showing in that box. what am I doing wrong ? or is there a problem with `JCrop` ?!! please help me.

This is the image when I upload :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qgEmA9RlKy_eilZohCLajGmnVfqWSB9E

This is the image when I submit and I get the error : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gSCurwZ50TF_nMZZcWnJ4keBsJmcQKEh

## Template Code:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('userRegister')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <div class="col-md-6 alert alert-danger {{!empty($errors->all()) ? 'show' : 'hide'}}">
        <ul style="text-align: right;" dir="rtl">
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="row col-md-12" dir="rtl">
    <div class="input-group col-md-4">
        <div class="container" dir="ltr">
            <div id="userpic" class="userpic">
                <div class="js-preview userpic__preview"></div>
                <div class="btn btn-success js-fileapi-wrapper">
                    <div class="js-browse">
                        <span class="btn-txt">انتخاب عکس</span>
                        <input type="file" name="filedata" id="filedata" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="js-upload" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="progress progress-success"><div class="js-progress bar"></div></div>
                        <span class="btn-txt">در حال بارگذاری</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="popup" class="popup" style="display: none">
            <div class="popup__body"><div class="js-img"></div></div>
            <div style="margin: 0 0 5px;text-align: center">
                <div class="js-upload btn btn_browse btn_browse_small">بارگذاری</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Validation Code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'filedata' => 'required|max:1024',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'filedata.max' => 'سایز تصویر نمیتواند بیش از 2 مگابایت باشد',
        'filedata.required' => 'وارد کردن تصویر الزامی است',

    ];
}
```

I get this error in my console :
`POST http://localhost:8000/server/ctrl.php?fileapi155834626282411 404 (Not Found)   FileAPI.min.js:2`

Comment: What is your jcrop javascript code for handling the file upload and cropping? Do you have any errors in the console after uploading/cropping an image?

Comment: @Jeemusu thank you for asking that , yes , when i upload the photo , i get this error

Comment: FileAPI.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/server/ctrl.php?fileapi155832644515911 404 (Not Found)
_send @ FileAPI.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ FileAPI.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ FileAPI.min.js:2
end @ FileAPI.min.js:2
check @ FileAPI.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
next @ FileAPI.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ FileAPI.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ FileAPI.min.js:2
FileAPI.min.js:2 Error: 404
FileAPI.min.js:2 xhr.end: 404 undefined

Comment: Have you included the FileApi javascript files in you page? Make sure all the files listed at this timestamp are included in your page like in the example. https://youtu.be/aflTCbGdzDc?t=113

Comment: var FileAPI = {
        debug:true,
        media:true,
        staticPath:'{{asset('crop-userpic\FileAPI')}}'
    };

Comment: could it be the problem ?

Comment: The `staticPath` is the path to the FileAPI javascript files, not the location where images are uploaded to. See the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.fileapi?activeTab=readme#fnfileapi
Those files need to be in your public directory.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to you in the comments, it would appear your getting 404 errors on the FileAPI javascript files.

You were using the following configuration for your FileAPI:

`var FileAPI = { debug:true, media:true, staticPath:'{{asset('crop-userpic\FileAPI')}}' };`

This was setting your `staticPath` to the `/resources/assets/crop-userpic/FileAPI` directory, which placed them outside of the webroot of your website.

You need to set the `staticPath` to the location of the FileAPI javascript files within your public directory so they can be accessed by jcrop.

## Example Usage

```
<!-- include jquery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Set FileAPI settings -->
<script>
    window.FileAPI = {
          debug: false,
          media: true,
          staticPath: '/js/jquery.fileapi/FileAPI/'
    };
</script> 
<script src="/js/jquery.fileapi/FileAPI/FileAPI.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.fileapi/FileAPI/FileAPI.exif.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.fileapi/jquery.fileapi.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jcrop/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
```

In the above example `staticPath` is the path to the files `FileAPI.min.js` and `FileAPI.exif.js`.

You should make sure you have those files accessible from within the `/public/js/jquery.fileapi/FileAPI/`.

Comment: I added an example. It doesn't matter if your using local or a webserver. You need to set the `staticPath` to the directory within your webroot/public (the directory with your index.php in it) directory that contains the FileAPI files.